# Development tool for iOS developer to study Cordova

Tags: software-development

I am an iOS developer, and I want to start with PhoneGap/Cordova study, but I don't know which development tool is suit me.

Which development tool for Cordova is suit to iOS developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Text editor for Javascript.

Long answer: PhoneGap/Cordova is a development framework by Apache that allows you to create applications on JavaScript and HTML, like websites, and then run them from iOS WebView, so it might look like a native app. It's also got many plugins, that provide you with JavaScript interfaces to the native capabilities, like detecting if there is Internet connection, controlling whether a device can go into a sleep mode, make payments through the App store, etc.
As this is a JavaScript thing, the development tool is usually something like Sublime Text Editor or Adobe Brackets and command line. To publish your apps you will also need XCode and an Apple Developer's account, which is $99 per year.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [WaveMaker Rapid](https://www.wavemaker.com/mobile/) to build hybrid mobile apps for iOS and Android. It uses the Cordova framework underneath and offers drag-&-drop development with mobile templates.